# How to evaluate $\int \frac{ds}{\sqrt{s^2-0.01}}$

Tags: integration

evaluate $$\int \frac{ds}{\sqrt{s^2-0.01}}$$
I think i should substitute $\sqrt{s^2-0.01}=t$ and then$\int \frac{dt}{s}$. But this doesn't make sense.

Comment: Hint:  let $s=0.1\sec\theta$.

Comment: Similar to: https://socratic.org/questions/how-do-you-integrate-int-1-sqrt-x-2-a-2-by-trigonometric-substitution

Comment: thanks a lot. i got the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps below,

$$I= \int \frac{ds}{\sqrt{s^2-0.01}}
=  \int \frac{10ds}{\sqrt{(10s)^2-1}}$$

With $10s=\cosh t$,

$$I= \int dt = t + C = \cosh^{-1}(10s) +C$$

Answer (score 0):

Substitute $$s=\frac{\sec(u)}{10}$$ then we get
$$ds=\tan(u)\sec(u)du$$